# Studio Time Lapse Photography

Tags: camera-settings, timelapse, studio, indoor, uv

I'm looking to do a time lapse video of a studio a UV make up shoot I've got coming up. I want to shoot the set up then actual shoot. As its a UV shoot the lighting will either very low or on during shots to organise things. Does anyone have any advice on, or could point me in the direction of tutorials that are focused on indoor Time-lapse videos with changing studio lighting?

Comment: UV = ultraviolet, right?

Answer (score 1):

1. Try using a digital camcorder that automatically adjusts exposure. Then speed up the video in post. Same effect as timelapse photography.
2. Look into MagicLantern.
3. If you shoot stills, shoot in RAW so you have ample dynamic range in post.

Answer (score 1):

1. Be sure there is enough time between frames for the exposure. For example, if shooting at the rate of one fps, a two second (or even a one second) exposure won't work. This may require increasing sensitivity (ISO) and/or using a lens with wide aperture.
2. Depending on the sensor and its internal filter, a UV-blocking filter may be needed, as UV may be incorrectly interpreted as one or more of the colors of the mosaic. [An ordinary skylight (1A)filter might be useful, or perhaps a stronger UV-2B filter.](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/explora/photography/buying-guide/uv-filters) Note that since lenses are not necessarily achromatic for UV, the UV portion of the image may be a blurred or hazy overlay on the visible-light image.